# Git: How to send a PR to a project to have original repo has a new empty branch from master?

Tags: git, github, branch, pull-request

How to send a PR to a project to have original repo has a new empty branch from master?

Explanation:

- I fork project "X".
- I want the original repo (github/x/X) to have a new branch called "new-branch".
- How can I send a pull-request, that if "merged", would create that empty new-branch?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it looks like it only works with `>= 1` commits

```
$ hub pull-request
Error creating pull request: Unprocessable Entity (HTTP 422)
No commits between svnpenn2:master and svnpenn:new-branch
```